# Proving that $|\sin z|> |1/z+i|$, $z$ is a complex number

Tags: complex-analysis

I already found a proof using the argument principle for a more general version.
[Prove the function $f(z)= \sin z +\frac{1}{z-a}$ has infinitely many zeros in the strip $|\mathrm{Im}z| < \epsilon.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/prove-the-function-fz-sin-z-frac1z-a-has-infinitely-many-zeros-in-th) 
But if possible I would like a hint on getting a shorter algebraic proof like a series of inequalities.
A possibly promising way is showing that $\sin^2x+\sinh^2y> [x/(x^2+(1+y)^2)]^2+[y+1/(x^2+(1+y)^2)]^2$.

Thank you.

Comment: Assuming you mean $|\sin z| > |\frac{1}{z+i}|$ this is certainly not true near $z=-i$. It is as certainly not true near points where $\sin z = 0$. (And if you mean $|\sin z| > |\frac{1}{z}+i|$, it doesn't help.)

Comment: @mrf: This is precisely what I was thinking before I saw your comment. :)